# Why are algebraic groups over a general field defined to be algebraic varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

In definitions of algebraic varieties over a field $k$, sources always seem to assume $k$ is algebraically closed. On the other hand, many uses of algebraic groups (for number theory at least) require us to be over a more general $k$, and yet they always seem to be defined as a certain kind of algebraic variety. Are authors implicitly considering the algebraic group as over $\bar{k}$ instead? Or are they implicitly taking a more general definition of variety? Or have I just not checked and correctly remembered enough sources?

Comment: Your question is too vague to get a useful answer. You should tell us what sources you are referring to. (You may even be able to answer your own question when you check the sources.)

Comment: If you look at Milne's notes on algebraic groups (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf), for example, he defines a varieties to be "geometrically reduced separated schemes of finite type over a field". I think many other authors use the same definition.

Comment: Algebraic varieties do not need to be defined only over an algebraically closed field, but you are unlikely to find that viewpoint developed in books focusing on classical algebraic geometry. See Definition 3.47 in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103338/so-many-different-varieties-which-one-is-this-serres-algebraic-variety.